# Preloading images from different servers with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cors, preloading

### Background:

I'm trying to preload some images in an AngularJS app before presenting them to the user to prevent them from "peeling" in. I my preload facility to return a promise resolved when the image has been downloaded.

### Current approach:

At the moment I'm using a simple `$http` call to download the image. Imagine `element` is an `<img>` tag with my image in it:

```
$http.get("my/image/url.jpg")
  .then( function() { 
    $animate.enter(element);
  });
```

This seems to work okay, but I  would appreciate any pointers if there's a better way to do it.

### Problem

I'm hitting issues with CORS I think. One application of this preloader is to load profile pictures from twitter. When I do this, my `$http.get` throws an error in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://path/to/img.jpg. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://my.server.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Is there a way to preload this sort of image?

I've created a [very simple plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sepzZIAd7JXmHNCVBYQ9?p=preview) demonstrating the problem - you'll need the console open to see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the standard ways to preload images - `img` tag that's not shown on screen would still force image loads.

Combined with Angular, sounds like a preloader directive would work perfectly.

No need to reinvent the wheel, just make the most use of Angular.

Comment: That sounds good, but how do I know when the image has loaded?

Comment: You can put onload listener on each.

Comment: Oh, of course! Completely forgot about that one, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, the good-old stuff still works. And it's really a perfect example to create a directive for.